# Cumulative data along with the original data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables .

**Input:**

[image]

I have joined with the calendar table and bring the data till current.

[image]

I need a output .

[image]

I tried a query with UNION and Aggregation but I need to query two times and aggregate the same table . Since the table is very big .Is there a option to do different way

```
SELECT ID ,PERIOD,SUM(AMOUNTYTD) AMOUNTYTD,SUM(AMOUNT) AMOUNT
FROM (
            SELECT ID ,b.PERIOD,SUM(AMOUNT) AMOUNTYTD,0 AMOUNT
            FROM transaction a RIGHT OUTER JOIN CALENDAR b
            ON b.PERIOD<=a.PERIOD
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ID ,PERIOD,0,SUM(AMOUNT)
            FROM transaction
            GROUP BY ID,PERIOD
    )
GROUP BY ID,PERIOD
```

Comment: I assume in your real-life data you have more than one ID. That will matter in whatever solution you find to your problem, so it should be reflected in your sample data you share here.

Comment: sure ..I have added two ID's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Showing the periodic amount side by side with the cumulative amount is easy - actually you only need to be able to create the correct table with the periodic amounts, the cumulative amounts are a simple application of analytic sum.

The key to joining the calendar table to the "input" data is to use a **partitioned** outer join - notice the `partition by (id)` clause in the join of the two tables. This causes the "inputs" data to be partitioned into separate sub-tables, one for each distinct `id`; the outer join to the calendar table is done separately for each such sub-table, and then the results are combined with a logical "union all".

```
with
  input (id, period, amount) as (
    select 1, 202010, 100 from dual union all
    select 1, 202011,  50 from dual union all
    select 2, 202011, 400 from dual
  )
, calendar (period) as (
    select 202010 from dual union all
    select 202011 from dual union all
    select 202012 from dual union all
    select 202101 from dual
  )
select id, period, amountytd, amount
from   (
         select i.id, period, i.amount, 
                sum(i.amount) over (partition by i.id order by period)
                  as amountytd
         from   calendar c left outer join input i partition by (id)
                           using (period)
       )
where  amountytd is not null
order  by id, period
;

 ID     PERIOD  AMOUNTYTD     AMOUNT
--- ---------- ---------- ----------
  1     202010        100        100
  1     202011        150         50
  1     202012        150           
  1     202101        150           
  2     202011        400        400
  2     202012        400           
  2     202101        400
```

Comment: Thank you . If I want to do this is in a different database like HANA where partitioned outer join is not supported is there a different way or I have to do the same way as mentioned in the question?. Because When we migrate it might be a problem for us.

Comment: @Satheesh - that information (that you also need a non-Oracle solution) should be included in your original question. To answer your question about HANA: I have no idea. I believe "partitioned outer joins" are part of the SQL standard; whether HANA supports them, I don't know - I have never even heard of HANA until I read your comment.

Comment: Thank you :) I will add it in a question. I searched a lot could not find the alternative so asked here.

Comment: @Satheesh - if it's not supported (for example, if it's proprietary to Oracle), partitioned outer join can be achieved as follows: You need a table with distinct id's (which you may have already); then do a CROSS JOIN of the calendar table with the distinct id table, and then left-outer-join the result to the "inputs" table. I believe behind the scenes that is how a "partitioned outer join" works anyway.

Comment: Brilliant . Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You have the query - `I have joined with the calendar table and bring the data till current.` let us assume it as `your_query`

You can use analytical function on it as follows:

```
Select t.*,
       Case when lead(amountytd) over (partition by id order by period) = amountytd 
            then null 
            else amountytd
       end as amount
  From (your_query) t
```